# Duda Oracle SQL (Fecha en números romanos)

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

la duda que me surge es como puedo pasar una cadena fecha a una cadena de números romanos. Solo soy capaz de pasar el mes pero no se me ocurre ninguna idea de hacer lo mismo pero con los días y el año.
Paso una imagen de lo que estoy intentando hacer por si no me explicado bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que me quede algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracios por leer :). ( "Soy un novato todavía en esto :("  )

Comment: Se ve interesante tu escenario, esto podría darte ideas: http://rdbms-insight.com/wp/2015/roman-numerals-to-decimal-in-sql/ Bienvenido a SOes!

Comment: Tu problema es más general: ¿Como convertir un numero arábigo a uno romano? dices que ya has resuelto los meses, ¿podrías compartir el código para ver que le falta para llevarlo a trabajar con milenios?